# Checking string to see if it has a comma in it

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How can the existing code be modified below such that if a string doesn't have a comma in it, it will just output the regular value.

```
function test() {

    //alert(get_ref_docs('12345678,987654321,14439696',1))

    alert(get_ref_docs('12345678',1)) -error received here.

alert(get_ref_docs('12345678',1)) -> would like the value alerted "12345678"



}
function get_ref_docs(str,num) {

/*Now strings will be a three element array where

    strings[0] contains the full string
    strings[1] contains the string before the first comma
    strings[2] contains everything after the first comma

*/
var x = str.match(/([^,]*),(.*)/);

return x[num]


}
```

Comment: what if your string has multiple values that you're passing in the arg to your function?

Comment: `([^,]*)(?:,(.*))?`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/jS2hq4/1) add this to your code:

```
var x = str.match(/[^,]+/g);
return x && x[num] ? x[num] : str;
```

If your string contains a comma, and your `num` is a valid index you will get your value.
If not, the original string will be returned.

For example:

```js
function test() {
    console.log(get_ref_docs('12345678,987654321,14439696', 2));    
    console.log(get_ref_docs('12345678', 1));
    console.log(get_ref_docs('12345678,987654321,14439696', 3));
}

function get_ref_docs(str, num) {
    var x = str.match(/[^,]+/g);
    return x && x[num] ? x[num] : str;
}

test();
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a regex here. Just [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on coma, like follows:

```
function get_ref_docs(str, num) {
    return str.split(",")[num - 1];
}
```